# CSS: How do I make these double lines that are vertically centered with the text?

Tags: css

[image]

I know border has a double attribute.  Do I need to hack some positions with border: double to get this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use CSS gradients for this, using color stops to create the lines.

http://jsfiddle.net/uUNLD/1/

```
p {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(silver 0, silver 1px, white 1px, white 4px, silver 4px, silver 5px, white 5px);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(silver 0, silver 1px, white 1px, white 4px, silver 4px, silver 5px, white 5px);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(silver 0, silver 1px, white 1px, white 4px, silver 4px, silver 5px, white 5px);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(silver 0, silver 1px, white 1px, white 4px, silver 4px, silver 5px, white 5px);
    background-position: 0 .4em;
}
```

Comment: You could also give it `background-size` and `background-position:center;`, to always keep it centered. http://jsfiddle.net/theazureshadow/uUNLD/2/ It's also possible to style the paragraph using `:first-line`, though less flexible (I had to use `:before` and `:after` to get padding to work).

Comment: Cool idea to use gradients :-)

Answer (score 2):

It would be difficult to do it with `double` but here is an alternate way of doing it.

http://jsfiddle.net/brenjt/SZG6X/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="box"><span class="text">BACKGROUND</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    width:100%;
    height:3px;
    border-top:1px solid #DDD;
    border-bottom:1px solid #DDD;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:3px;
}

.box .text {
    background: #FFF;
    padding:3px 6px;
    font-size:0.9em;
    color:#DDD;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a span for the text, instead of setting it with css to inline?

Comment: Not really any more difficult to do with `double` (`border-bottom:3px double #DDD; line-height:0`), unless you mean with some amount of control over the spacing of the lines -- in that case I'd *almost* say impossible (you could technically do it with masking using overflow:hidden).

Answer (score 0):

I like the effect. Might use it someday

```
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #ccc
  }
  h1:before {
    content: "";
    border-top: solid 1px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 39%;/* might need some tweaking */
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;

  }

  h1 span {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 4px;
    position: relative;
  }
```

it uses this html:

```
<h1><span>Hello World</span></h1>
```

live version: http://jsbin.com/abasif/

Comment: I don't see anything glaringly *wrong* with this post other than maybe lack of support for `:before` in crappy browsers, so I'm voting it back up to 0. Whoever downvoted should have left an explanation, I'm not seeing the problem...

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>

h1 { color: gray; height: 10px; }
h1:before, h1:after { content: ''; border: 1px solid gray; width: 35%; display: inline-block; height: 5px; border-left: none; border-right: none; margin: 0 10px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hn7Hk/